# YII 2 get user identity after automatic logged out

Tags: php, session, yii2

In Yii 2 I have to store user's login and logged out entry in one table. Still now when user is logged in and manually logged out that time I have store login and logout data(`datetime`) in table.

But when any user logged out automatically when his session expired automatically that time I didn't get the user identity and that's why I am not getting the logged out data(`datetime`).

My automatic session expired time is 1 hour.

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass'       => 'common\models\Users',
    'enableAutoLogin'     => true,
    'idParam'             => '_frontend',
    'identityCookie'      => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],            
    'class'               => 'nill\forum\PhpBBWebUser',
    'authTimeout'         => 3600,
    //'absoluteAuthTimeout' => 3600,
],
'session' => [
    // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
    'name' => 'advanced-frontend',            
],
```

I want to get user identity after user logged out automatically or his session expired.

Comment: Have you checked beforeLogout() function in which you can store the logout datetime information. Link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#beforeLogout%28%29-detail

Comment: @Chinmay, I have used beforeLogout() function in model class Users and print '123' but I am not come in to this function before logout. When I am click on logout link it will show me login screen and user is logged out.

Comment: Can you show your code/function?

Comment: `protected function beforeLogout ($identity)
    {
        echo 'test';exit;
    }`

Comment: Can anyone help help me more?

Comment: Can beforeLogout() called when user's session expired and logged out automatically? I am not going to this function if user's session is expired and user logged out automatically.

Comment: You have not called the parent implementation. Read the link carefully, "make sure you call the parent implementation so that the event is triggered."

Comment: Now I can call the beforeLogout() method. Please guide further.

Comment: What you ask is not possible because PHP is stateless. `beforeLogout` is not called when session expires automatically (only manually works here).

Comment: @Bizley, That's ok. But in my Yii2 website I need to show users last login datetime and total time(in hours) in backend. So How can I manage? Please help me.

Comment: You can save the identity when user logs in and keep it on the fixed timer equal to the session expiration time. Every time logged user performs any action you need to restart this timer. When user logs out manually you save its info and remove the previously saved identity. When user doesn't log out manually timer runs out and you can save the stored identity as this user's one. The problem is this is not accurate but should be enough. It's not straightforward solution so I can not give you the code for it, it depends on your system.

Comment: @Bizley, Don't worry. Can you please provide the code. It's very useful for me.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not. I don't know how you want to store the identity, what db are you using and so on. The general idea above should be enough for you to create the mechanism on your own.

Comment: Ohk. No issue @Bizley Thanks for reply.